# Active records (Rails) conditional validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, conditional-statements, rails-activerecord

I need arguments a and b to be required UNLESS c is provided. I tried:

```
slop_opts = Slop.parse(ARGV.map(&:strip)) do |o|
  o.string '--a', 'a(required)', required: true, unless: :c
  o.string '--b', 'b(required)', required: true, unless: :c
  o.string '--c', 'c(required, unless a and b specified)'
...
```

should work (but it's not working for me). Then:

```
o.string '--c', 'c(required, unless a and b specified)', required: true, unless (:a && :b)
```

Is incorrect. what would be the correct syntax of such sentence?

I tried:

```
...required: true, unless: -> {:a && :b}
```

And it didn't work either...

Help will be greatly appreciated!!

Thank you!

Comment: Try using a [`Proc` or a `lambda`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-proc-with-if-and-unless)

Comment: @AbM I apologize for my ignorance in Rails and Ruby in general. I tried:  `unless: -> { :a && :b }` as well as `Proc.new { :a && :b }` and the interpreter (or compiler?) says`syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end` and `Can't assign to true`. Could you shoot a hint? Thanks!

Comment: @AbM The problem was other. It did work! Thanks a lot!!